# How to check if a SQLite database is an in-memory database or not

Tags: sqlite

I have an handler for a connection to an sqlite3 database. I would like to know if the database is an in-memory database or not.

Is there any API to do so?

Comment: Which SQLite client library are you using, and for what language?

Answer (score 5):

At the C API layer you can use [`sqlite3_db_filename`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/db_filename.html) to get the filename. If it's NULL or empty you've got a temporary or in-memory database.

> The sqlite3_db_filename(D,N) interface returns a pointer to a filename associated with database N of connection D. The main database file has the name "main". If there is no attached database N on the database connection D, or ***if database N is a temporary or in-memory database, then this function will return either a NULL pointer or an empty string.***

Whatever client API library you're using likely acts the same: the filename will be empty.